# React Native ScrollView above another ScrollView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make something similar to the Instagram ScrollView which is inside the "Search" screen of the app. If you are using iOS and see the app, you will see that when you start typing the username of an user, a ScrollView overlaps the feed ScrollView.

For this I am doing:

```
 <ScrollView>
    <HorizontalStoriesList />
    ...
    <Animated.ScrollView
      testID="SearchUsersList"
      style={[
        StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
        {
          opacity: searchUsersListOpacity,
          backgroundColor: colors.white,
        },
      ]}
    >
      <UsersList data={data} />
    </Animated.ScrollView>
 </ScrollView>
```

My problem is that the ScrollView which is more above doesn't have the good height, instead of using its own height it uses the height of the parent scroll view. Also, I am not able to touch the components that are behind this scrollview (The HorizontalStoriesList, for example. I have tried with pointerEvents="none" but this make the Animated Scroll View (the one which is more above) to be untouchable.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: try using `contentContainerStyle`?

Comment: Yeah but didn't work. I used: contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}